# java compile package does not found ever after adding all required jars and also verified with different versions

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee, netbeans

The package `org.awakefw.commons.api.client` does not exist even after adding all the jars related to it. I tried with the following jars:

- awake-file-1.0.2.jar
- awake-sql-1.0.7.jar
- awake-sql-1.1.jar

Also tryied other jars with more other versions.

[image: Invalid packages]

Comment: what is your question ?

Comment: its about the issue with the jar files . for JAVA Sockets , i included      requiered jar files but event though i am getting error as "specified package is not there" . I also tried with different versions of awake-file and awake-sql ect . So please let me know if anybody want further information .

Comment: "adding all the jars related to it" adding them where? Is this a Spring app? Do you have configuration files? Do you have an error/exception/something?

Comment: yes it is spring application , it is having all the configuration files . i updated jar files as libraries path in NetBeans .

Comment: What is the exact error you are getting? Also, can you make a print-screen of your Netbeans instance showing the project structure?

Comment: i have taken screen shot of that error , i attached it .

Answer (score 0):

Your scenario should work.
Try this:

1. Select the jars with issues from the Project structure list, right-click and choose "Remove"
2. Right-click on the project name, choose Properties, go to Libraries
3. In the Compile tab, click on "Add JAR/Folder", browse to your jars and add them
4. Click OK
5. If the packages still have compile time issues, Right-click on the project and choose "Clean and Build"